# Webview freezed after using the stopLoading of react-native-webview

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, react-navigation, react-native-webview

I want to open a webpage in React native Webview and the hrefs (links) to be opened in the default browser. I tried using the stopLoading method of Webview but it freezes the view. I successfully achieved this using the answer on this thread.

[The method stopLoading of react-native-webview causes the website to freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043298/the-method-stoploading-of-react-native-webview-causes-the-website-to-freeze/57057681?noredirect=1#comment114360036_57057681)

But in some cases, randomly, Upon click of href link, it opens the webpage in the Webview as well beside opening it in the default browser. I want it to be opened in the brwoser only. Please check what's I am doing wrong here. Or is there any better approach to achieve this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
LoadingIndicatorView() {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        color="#009b88"
        size="large"
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent :'center', }}
      />
    );
  }

  handleWebViewRequest = request => {
    const {url} = request;
    Linking.openURL(url);
    return false;
  }

  render() {

    let uri = 'https://www.google.com/';
    let sku = this.props.route.params.sku;
    let location = this.props.route.params.location;

    return (
      <WebView
      ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}  
      source={{ uri: uri, method: 'POST', body: 'device=tablet&search='+sku+'&ref='+location }}
      renderLoading={this.LoadingIndicatorView}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.handleWebViewRequest.bind(this)}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />    
    );
  }
```

Comment: I find the random behaviour very strange. But I had a look in my code and saw that I added 'this.webview.goBack()' after opening the URL externally and afterwards I return true instead of false. This is most certainly a little to hacky for being a good solution. Unfortunately I haven't been working on that project for a while now, so I fear, I am of no further use here '^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added stopLoading in the method that gets invoked for `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`

```js
webViewRef.current.stopLoading();
```

where webViewRef is the ref of the webView

```js
ref = { webViewRef }
```

Comment: Can you please correct me if I am doing wrong: I am trying this: 

ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={ref.current.stopLoading();}